# Import txt to excel file in matlab containing numbers and letters

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a .txt file containing a header and both numbers and letters in each cell.
The structure of the file is the following:

```
Measure Time;Ref pO2;Ref Spot;Ref Inst; 20170512_141213;196;1; 202-250;20170512_161213;250;2; 252-260;...
```

There is a header and then all the values, separated by `;`.

Which command can I use?

Comment: Which command can I use for what? There is no actual question here.

Comment: Format your code while you're at it.

Comment: You appear to have a track record of unanswered questions. Please see the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to better understand what is needed in a good question. Then edit your question so that it is easier to answer. This will include a *formatted* example of your input data, what you might have tried, and precisely what you want to achieve. Then accept answers which help you!

Comment: And accept the answers that helped you.